# Section and Article usage with example

Tags: html

There are a lot of different answers and after a week I am more confused than before.
The main problem is section and articles.
Let's make an example, this page describes a town:

```
<h1>TownName</h1>
<p>Description</p>

<h2>What to see</h2>
<h3>Sightseeing Nr1</h3>
<p>Its description</p>
<h3>Sightseeing Nr2</h3>
<p>Its description</p>
...
<h2>How to get</h2>
<h3>By car</h3>
<p>Description</p>
<h3>By train</h3>
<p>Description</p

<h2>Map</h2>
<p>Description</p>

<h2>...</h2>
...
etc.
```

There are h3 for some h2, for some nope. Should I use article for each h2 and a nested article for h3 too? (The context can be separated, so..)

Or should I use sections for h3?

Or should I use section for blocks of "h2" and article for each h3?

h1 with its description is an article or section too?

It's so difficult, also I have added an image of a page that I projected, I am almost sure that I don't have to use section to wrap aside and main elements..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zhenya, This is from W3 Schools

```
**Nesting Semantic Elements**
In the HTML5 standard, the <article> element defines a complete, self-contained block of related elements.

The <section> element is defined as a block of related elements.

Can we use the definitions to decide how to nest elements? No, we cannot!

On the Internet, you will find HTML pages with <section> elements containing <article> elements, and <article> elements containing <sections> elements.

You will also find pages with <section> elements containing <section> elements, and <article> elements containing <article> elements.
```

Comment: So it's not easy to understand the right choise in the current example, where I have h1, mane h2, and some of them have h3... Which of those are articles and whick are sections. They all can be considered as "complete element" for me... I think

Comment: You can place either 'article' in 'section' or 'section' in 'article' as per your idea. And you can use h1/h2/h3 in anyway as per the design. (tags in hierarchical flow ). Its better you check the definition of section and article for getting the idea.